# CSV Find Nearly the same value and make them identical and filter the values

Tags: csv, sorting, filter, product, parent

Community!

Story: I am trying to upload a CSV file with a huge batch of products to my e-commerce shop. But there are many very similar products, but all with every column slightly different. And luckily the plugin I use can handle this, but it needs the same title for the entire product range or some reference to its parent product. The reference is sadly not there.

Now I want to know how I can find values in a CSV file that are nearly the same (in SQL there was something called '%LIKE%') to structure the table appropriately. I can hardly describe what I want to achieve, but here is an example for what I'm looking for.

**I basically want to transform this table:**

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      ID       |     Title     |      EAN      |      ...      |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      1        | AquaMat 3.6ft |   1234567890  |      ...      |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      2        | AquaMat 3.8ft |   1234567891  |      ...      |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      3        |  AquaMat 4ft  |   1234567892  |      ...      |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

**into this:**

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      ID       |     Title     |      EAN      |      ...      |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      1        |    AquaMat    |   1234567890  |      ...      |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      2        |    AquaMat    |   1234567891  |      ...      |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      3        |    AquaMat    |   1234567892  |      ...      |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

**The extra data can be **scraped**.** Can I do this with Excel? With Macros? With Python?

Thank you for taking time and reading this.

If you have any questions, than feel free to ask.

**EDIT:**

The Title column contains products with completely different names and might even contain more whitespaces. And some products might have 1 attribute but others have up to 3 attributes. But this can be sorted manually.

And with nearly the same I mean as you can see in the table. The Title's are basically the same but not identical. I want to remove the attributes from them. Also, there are no other columns with any more details, only numbers and the attributes that I am trying to cut of the title!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea using Python and .split():

```
import csv

with open('testfile.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8-sig") as inputfile:

 csv_reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter=',')
   with open('outputfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as outputfile:
      w = csv.writer(outputfile)
      header=['ID','Title','EAN','Product','Attr1','Attr2','Attr3']
      w.writerow(header)
      for row in csv_reader:
          if row[0]=='ID':
              header_row=True
              pass
          else:
              header_row=False
              list=row[1].split()
              for item in list:
                  # if you want, you can add some other conditions on the attribute (item) in here
                  row.append(item)
              if not header_row:
                  print('row: {}'.format(row))
                  w.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we're going to need more information about what, exactly you're trying to achieve.  Is it just the extra text after the "Aquamat" (for example) that you want to remove?  If so, you could simply loop through the csv file and remove anything after "Aquamat" in the "Title" column.

I assume from your description, though, that there is more to it than this.

Perhaps a starting point would be to let us know what you mean by "nearly the same".  Do you want exactly what SQL means by LIKE, or something different?

EDIT:

You might check out Python's Regular Expressions: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).  If your "nearly the same" can be translated into a regex expression as described in the docs, then you could use python to loop through the csv file and search/replace terms based on the regular expression.

Are all the "nearly the same" things in the "Title" column, or could they be in other columns as well?

Comment: +1 Just edited my post! I know about Regex but it might get a bit dirty in combination with python and CSV.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info.  If I understand correctly, you would like to take the contents of a cell in the "Title" column and separate it into a product name and one or more attributes.  The product name and attributes are separated by one or more whitespaces.  If I am correct, Python has a .split method: [link](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html) that can handle this.  I'm happy to assist with this if I'm on the right track with your question.